# Xubuntu on 10 year old iMac - change to Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, usb, mac

Brand new Linux user here, eager to transition from macOS to Ubuntu. I have a ten year old iMac, and I successfully installed Xubuntu on this very old iMac, and it's worked like a charm. However, I decided to switch to Ubuntu, as it seems easier to learn the main version. So I downloaded the ISO, created a bootable USB using Etcher, just like I did when I successfully installed Xubuntu, but now I don't know how to boot from this USB, so I can erase the HD and do a clean install of Ubuntu.

When I restart now, with the USB stick already in the Mac, I get "System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults." and then the Xubuntu login screen eventually appears. I have tried holding down F12, Shift and Alt, and I get various other results, not the first install screen for Ubuntu.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, in this forum full of people who are way way more sophisticated computer users than I, but what is the correct procedure here? Is there some way I can be logged into Xubuntu and tell the system that after restart I want to boot from the USB stick?

I can handle advanced instructions, try using GRUB and all that, but if so I hope someone can direct me to or maybe even type out here, very detailed instructions (assume I'm an idiot, I won't be offended).

Hope you can help. Long live open source and Linux!

UPDATE: I tried holding down F2 whilst rebooting, and this time I got a black screen with four lines of white text with different options, that I could choose from using up/down arrow keys and return. The first option was "Try without installing", but I chose the second option, "Install Ubuntu". After clicking Return, the screen has been black for several minutes. At least I know I got in some kind of contact with the USB install stick, right?

UPDATE 2: I've decided that with a computer this old, it's probably better using a lightweight version of Ubuntu after all, so I'm sticking with Xubuntu. But maybe a solution could be posted anyway, as it's possible others may benefit from this exchange.